# How to redirect in laravel jetstream?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, fortify, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am using laravel 8 with jetstream I want to know that how can I direct different users like admin or user to different routes?
RouteServiceProvider has Public const Home = '';
but it only direct to a one route

Comment: redirect them when?

Comment: on login when admin and user login

Comment: Looks like this is not properly support by fortify yet as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/77), but [this](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects) article explains how you can create 
 your own `LoginResponse` to handle it.

Comment: I have already read that but I am not sure what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help this is how I solve the problem

I created a new view for admin `"admin/index.blade.php"`

Then I assign the role of a developer to the admin, then I use this in my route

```
Route::middleware(['role:developer'])->get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin.index');
})->name('admin');
```